# Spring Security X.509 Preauth

Tags: gwt, spring-security, pre-authentication

I'm using Spring Security 2.x's Preauthentication with X.509 certificates.

I get the `certificateText` via `HttpServletRequest.getAttribute("CERTIFICATE")`.

Sometimes, the above call returns `""` (empty). I believe it occurs when the HTTP session has expired.

What would explain why `HttpServletRequest.getAttribute("CERT")` returns empty?

**EDIT** In Kerberos, for example, the ticket is available in every HTTP request. Is the cert not always in X.509 HTTP requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Please access to certificate using this code:
   `X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[]) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");`
2. Certificate is always populated to request after successful client certificate authentication.

Ensure your support long certificate chain:

1. Add the max_packet_size propery to the worker.properties file
   `worker.ajp13w.max_packet_size=65536`
2. Add the packetSize propery to the configuration of Ajp connector in the Tomcat configuration \conf\server.xml
   `<Connector port="8089" 
              enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" protocol="AJP/1.3" packetSize="65536"/>`

Apache logs:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#accesslog
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#errorlog
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#loglevel

Comment: So if the client certificate authentication failed, then the HTTP session would not include the `javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate` attribute? I had added log statements to print out `request.getAttributeNames()` and then iterate through them. Sometimes there would be no `javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate` certificate.

And the key to finding out why it failed is the Apache logs?

Comment: How you connect Apache and your servlet container? AJP?

Comment: Apache and Tomcat talk via `mod_jk`. But I do have this property set: `conf.d/workers.properties:worker.eurekastreams.type=ajp13`

Comment: per your edit, I already had those values set in Apache and Tomcat config.

Comment: Do you have a specific certificate that do not appear or a same certificate sometimes disappear?

Comment: I'm not sure. Please tell me why do you ask? (I'm curious how you're thinking about this problem). Also, Spring Security docs say `If no certificate is found, or no corresponding user could be found then the security context will remain empty.` So, why wouldn't the certificate be found?

Comment: I know pretty well both SpringSecurity and ClientAuthentication. SpringSecurity just bring the information from the request populated by Apache. In case the information not exists SpringSecurity will return empty context.
So, I suppose that somehow the client authentication failed for some requests and you should realize why.
Did you find something in Apache logs?

Comment: I saw these errors in `apache-error` log, `Re-negotiation handshake failed: Not accepted by client!?`. This ServerFault post (http://serverfault.com/questions/410925/configuring-client-certificate-authentication-in-apache) has an accepted answer that says to update my `OpenSSL` and `Apache` software to fix the problem.